# \mathbf with greeksymbol is not working using katex

Tags: katex

I would like to get the all the greeksymbols should be display with bold (and not bold-italic). But \mathversion{bold} and \mathversion{normal} is not working in KaTeX. How do configure to work `\mathversion{bold}` and `\mathversion{normal}`?

Answer (score 0):

For `\mathbf` with greek symbols we can use direct unicode in HTML file. `\mathbf{η}` or `\texbf{η}` it's rendering correct output in the HTML file.